# Formatting rows based on row number

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to format rows using openpyxl based on the row number. This is my attempt at this:

```
for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=3, max_col=26):
    if ((row-3)//4)+1 % 2 == 0:
        for cell in row:
            cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="A0ACEA", fill_type="solid")
    else:
        for cell in row:
            cell.fill = PatternFill(bgColor="D3D7F0", fill_type="solid")
```

I get the below error. I understand what it means but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
if ((row-3)//4)+1 % 2 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row you're getting in your first for loop is a tuple, not an int.  When you try `row-3`, you're getting an error because you cannot do arithmetic with tuples and integers.

You're getting the row itself, rather than the index of the row. This is exactly what `enumerate` is for.

Try this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(ws2.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=3, max_col=26)):
    if ((i-3)//4)+1 % 2 == 0:
```